# Could not find Unity Package Manager local server application at [d:/games/Unity/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/Server/UnityPackageManager.exe]

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I start the Unity3D 2020.2.1f1 then this window pops up:

```
Could not find Unity Package Manager local server application at 
[d:/games/Unity/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/Server/UnityPackageManager.exe]
Missing files could be the result of an antivirus action or a corrupt Unity installation.
```

[image: error dialog]

The mentioned file doesn't exist. The trick is that I reinstalled everything, copied this file in advance and realized that when you start it is got deleted. How can this be solved?

So far I tried the following:

- Reinstalled the Unity and hub
- Cleaned the registry through CCleaner
- The firewall is disabled, and the incoming/outgoing rules for unity.exe file are enabled
- There is no antivirus in the system
- I set the environment variables in Windows

I tried a bunch of solutions that I could find, but nothing helps. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: did you solve this? im getting same error

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you are trying to create a new projec in Unity with a version that failed to fully install or is no longer installed on your machine. Please double check the Editor and Supporting Packages you have installed in Unity Hub and then when creating your project double check the version number that Unity Hub autoselects to make sure it picked the right version.
[image]